# Getting result of multiple SELECT statements from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am practicing on creating a stored procedure which has multiple `select` queries in it and I want to return back the result of all these queries back as one dataset so I could put them in a array.

But from what I have written my stored procedure only return the results of first query and not the rest.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getPost
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT TOP 5 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 order by dtetme DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 order by dtetme DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 order by [hits] DESC;
SELECT TOP 5 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 AND category=(SELECT id FROM category where name='Small') order by dtetme DESC;
SELECT TOP 5 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 AND category=(SELECT id FROM category where name=’Medium’) order by dtetme DESC;
SELECT TOP 1 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 AND category=(SELECT id FROM category where name='Big’) order by dtetme DESC;
SELECT TOP 3 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 order by newid();
GO
```

I am using MS SQL Server.
Kindly Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place a `UNION` between each `SELECT`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getPost
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT TOP 5 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 order by dtetme     DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 order by dtetme DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 order by [hits] DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 AND category=(SELECT id FROM category where name='Small') order by dtetme DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 5 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 AND category=(SELECT id FROM category where name=’Medium’) order by dtetme DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 1 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 AND category=(SELECT id FROM category where name='Big’) order by dtetme DESC
UNION
SELECT TOP 3 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 order by newid();
GO
```

Note that if you use `UNION`, you won't get any duplicates and your query will probably be slower on large datasets. If you use `UNION ALL` instead you may get duplicates, but the query will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Union them together

```
SELECT TOP 5 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 title,summary,cphoto,pId FROM [post] WHERE [status]=1 
UNION ALL
...
order by title DESC;
```